# Taking an IE screenshot returns a black image

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm building a console app which will connect to different computers in the network and take browser screenshots of a webpage.
Using Selenium 2.47.1 to set up server & nodes. The console app runs in the PC which is set up as selenium hub.
The screenshot is fine in firefox,chrome,ie from the hub computer.
The screenshot is also fine in firefox in remote pc.
But with IE it returns a black image.
Both the hub and node computers run on windows 7 64-bit, have IE11. I am using the 64bit IEDriver in both PCs.
The node computer is not locked.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   IWebDriver NewDriver = null;
   using (NewDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://172.165.10.111/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer()))
    {
      if (NewDriver != null)
       {
         NewDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
         NewDriver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1804, 1096);
         Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)NewDriver).GetScreenshot();
         ICapabilities capabilities = ((RemoteWebDriver)NewDriver).Capabilities;
         ss.SaveAsFile(@"C:\Path\123.png", ImageFormat.Png);
         NewDriver.Quit();
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 11):

It's because your screen is locked, or a screensaver is running.

You will need to turn off your screensaver and configure windows to never lock itself when not in use.  To turn off your screensaver:

- Click the Start button.
- Click Control Panel.
- In the search box, type screen saver.
- Click Turn screen saver on or off.

Then modify your screensaver settings.  Make sure you have unchecked "On resume, display logon screen".

While you're in the control panel it's probably worth checking the power options and making sure the machine isn't going to sleep or powering down after a set period of time as well.

You will also want to use VNC or remote assist to access the GUI.  If you RDP in it will lock the screen for the local user who is currently logged in and again it will lock the screen when you disconnect.

Finally don't use the 64-bit IE driver, you should be using the 32Bit one.  Nobody runs the 64Bit version of IE (even if they have a 64Bit capable machine).

****** ***Edit*** 
Adding a bit more info from a credible and reputable source ******

Below is a link to a post on the Selenium users forum where Jim Evans (the developer who wrote the IEDriver binaries) explains this:

http://selenium.10932.n7.nabble.com/IE-Screenshots-are-black-when-not-connected-via-Remote-Desktop-to-the-VM-hosting-an-IE-Node-td37004.html

This quote in particular about taking screenshots when you have disconnected from a RDP instance:

> It's a known limitation. There is no known workaround. Complain to
>   Microsoft. They're the ones that make the PrintWindow API (which is
>   the proper API to use when grabbing screen captures) behave that way.
>   Either that, or if you discover a way to make it work, you're welcome
>   to submit a patch.

He explains how the screenshot code works in more detail on his blog here:

http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/screenshots-sendkeys-and-sixty-four.html

Specifically:

> The IE driver takes screenshots using the PrintWindow API function.
>   PrintWindow can only take a screenshot of the visible portion of any
>   given window, which means that in order to get a full-page screenshot
>   (as required by the WebDriver API), the window must be sized large
>   enough to display the entire page without scroll bars. However,
>   Windows does not allow the window to be resized larger than the
>   visible screen resolution. When we ask IE to resize itself, a
>   WM_GETMINMAXINFO message is sent on a resize event so the IE can
>   figure how large a window can be. By intercepting that message with a
>   hook, and modifying the max values, we can trick IE into thinking that
>   a window can be sized greater than the screen resolution would
>   otherwise allow.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this might be a known issue with configuration:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3536

From what @ShubhasmitGupta mentioned above, it does look like the IE driver hands out black-screen screenshots when the desktop is locked (I'm assuming this has something to do with DWM/Explorer not rendering windows).

There's [a workaround](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3536#c9) involving not locking the targeted computer when connecting to it via RDP. Essentially, you create a *disconnect.bat* file with the following contents:

```
tscon rdp-tcp#0 /dest:console
```

I'm not sure exactly when that's supposed to be run, but the concept is to prevent the test computer from being locked when connecting via Remote Desktop. If that helps, great; I haven't been able to test the workaround myself and figure out how to set it up. Maybe someone else can write a more concise answer.

Comment: The remote pc is not locked and i dont find that workaround comprehensive or to use it in my c# code

Answer (score 1):

Open up the **Service Control Manager** -- You can do WindowsKey+R (run) and type services.msc and hit <ENTER> and it'll start up.

Find the service and right click it and choose **properties** from the context menu.

**Allow Service to Interact With Desktop**

Now, select the Log On tab.
You want to make sure the checkbox is selected for "Allow service to interact with the desktop".

You can see it in the image below.

**Note**: I don't have that service so I just picked another one in the sample picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try removing below line

```
//NewDriver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1804, 1096);
```

maximize your browser instead.

```
NewDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a sneaky suspicion that IE has been rendering with DirectX for some time and [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh237264(v=vs.85).aspx) certainly seems to indicate that this is the case... which would explain why you'd have problems as GDI based screen grabs won't work with DirectX surfaces.

I'm saying this is an absolute... just a hunch

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a while back, and though I don't completely understand the problem it was basically that the process executing selenium was running under a system account and thus the IE gui was visible only in session 0, whereas session 1 was showing only a black screen.

The solution which worked for me was to create a local user account on the remote host, keep that user permanently signed in and unlocked so that they have an interactive desktop available, then run your selenium app/tests as that user. I know that is not ideal, but as we had dozens of old boxes lying around, it didn't hurt to use one as a dedicated test server. Hope that helps somewhat!

Sorry, not enough rep to add this as a comment.

Comment: Can you use Jenkins in the described scenario? If so, how did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an interesting hint...

...working with Selenium 2.47.x and 2.52.0 Jenkins, RDP and IE 11 in mode IE 7 (setting by website) on the server Win 2008. Additional to this, I have to screens connected to my PC.

If I am disconnected from the Win Server (not logged off) I have two situations:

The JAVA prog on the Server produces black boxes or real screenshoots. The difference is just one marker in RDP options in the display part on the local RDP configuration of my client (Win 7).

I have not an english spoken display so I hope the translation may ok.

The configuration detail is: "using all monitors by remote session"

If this marker is set, I get real screen shoots. If this one is not set I have black boxes. I can't explain why, but it works in this way...

Answer (score -1):

Windows would sometimes cause black screens because the machine/desktop was not in use.

Comment: The remote desktop isn't locked in my case